# How do I tell a compiler to "ignore" a class?

Tags: java

In my project, I have a non-essential class that does not work right now. I made some changes to other classes, and want to test them out. I commented out all the references to the class, and no errors are returned from them. The only problems are in the bad class. However, I receive an exception anyways. **How can I basically "comment out" an entire class without deleting or moving it?** I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: `/* public class ... */`

Comment: It gives me a bunch of token and misplaced construct errors when I try to wrap the class in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. Move it elsewhere, then bring it back when you're ready.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, but it seems like there isn't another way.

Comment: Don't comment it all the way out.  Leave in the package statement and `public class MyClass {}`.

Comment: How are you compiling? Normally, you *specify* source files to the compiler; not files you don't want *compiled*.

Comment: How about renaming java class? e.g. `YourClass.java` to `YourClass.java_` or `YourClass._java` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try excluding class from build path in your IDE.
In Eclipse it's right click → Build Path → Exclude

Netbeans and others should have similar option (for Netbeans try Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Includes/Excludes)